# Error When Using biocLite as an installer in rpy2 python library

Tags: r, python, rpy2

I am running into an error when I tried to run the following lines of code, the `error` at line 3:

```
1 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
2 base = importr('base')
3 base.source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
4 biocinstaller = importr("BiocInstaller")
5 biocinstaller.biocLite("seqLogo")
```

`rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error: With R version 3.5 or greater, install Bioconductor packages using BiocManager; see https://bioconductor.org/install`

How can I use `BiocManager` installer instead of `biocLite`  and reflect that on my code? I couldn't find any documentation or source that talk about this error from within Python.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need upgrade your R base version.

Comment: Definitely recommend installation via Conda as @zorbax points out. This normal stuff for installing rpy2 As a word of warning further errors with rpy2 are also normal and as a general rule of thumb rpy2 is a nightmare. For R's ggplot2 via rpy2 is outdated and will not import the full funcationality of the ggplot2 into Python3. This is irregular given have important ggplot2 is as a graphing package. After my experience I would use subprocessing into R rather than deal with rpy2 again

Answer (score 2):

You're using an outdated version of R. You can use the R 4.0 from `conda-forge` channel, just create an environment with `r-base` and then install `rpy2`, the latest version compatible with R 4.0 is available through `pip`

```
conda create -n rpy2 -c conda-forge r-base
conda activate rpy2
pip install rpy2
```

Now you can use rpy2 with R 4.0 in your python code.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r('install.packages("BiocManager", '
           'repos="http://cran.r-project.org")')
robjects.r('BiocManager::install("seqLogo")')
robjects.r('library(seqLogo)')
```

Remember deactivate your env with `conda deactivate`.

Comment: Thank you so much this work! but when I do the same thing for "GenomicAlignments" package I get error:    
    raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in (new("nonstandardGenericFunction", .Data = function (expr, envir = parent.frame(),  : 
  object 'GenomicAlignments' not found

Comment: I can't replicate you error. I did `robjects.r('BiocManager::install("GenomicAlignments")')` and then `robjects.r('library(GenomicAlignments)')` and it works.

Comment: I am unable to do this for pcalg (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcalg/pcalg.pdf). Can I see a minimal working example?